# MasterDetail Icon not shown if the page is navigated to from Login Page at start

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So my app tries at the start to log in with saved between sessions login information.

Something like this:

```
public App()
{
    if (DoLogin(UserData) == LoginStatus.Success)
        MainPage = new NavigationPageNoLine(new MainAppPage());
    else
        MainPage = new NavigationPageNoLine(new LoginPage());
}
```

where MainAppPage is a MasterDetailPage.

If there is UserData saved between the sessions of the app, then the MainPage is the MasterDetailsPage where everything is in place and the MasterDetails icon appears as it should be:
[image]

But when there is no UserData saved, the LoginPage appears, where, after the login process is completed, I set:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPageNoLine(new MainAppPage());
```

Everything is ok except in this case the master details icon does not appear in the page:
[image]

The drawer is working perfectly in both cases. Only the icon disappears in the Login scenario.

How to make sure the icon appears in all cases?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is the MainAppPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              x:Class="AppName.View.MainAppPage"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AppName.Helpers;assembley=Colors"

              Title="{i18n:Translate NewsPageTitle}">
 <MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <ContentPage Title ="Options">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="5,0,5,0">

    <ListView IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                ItemsSource="{x:Static apploc:Settings.OptionMenuItems}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
                HasUnevenRows="False"
                x:Name="ListViewOptions"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <Grid Padding="5,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding IconSource}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       TextColor="{x:Static local:Colors.PrimaryText}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       FontAttributes="Bold">
                  <Label.FontSize>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="14" Android="14" WinPhone="11" />
                  </Label.FontSize>
                </Label>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
  <ContentPage Title ="Feeds">
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
 ...
    </AbsoluteLayout>
   </ContentPage>
 </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

and here is my MainAppPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using AppName.Resx;

namespace AppName.View
{
  public partial class MainAppPage : MasterDetailPage
  {
    public MainAppPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListViewOptions.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => await NavigateTo(e.SelectedItem as OptionsMenuItem);
    }

    private async Task NavigateTo(OptionsMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem == null)
            return;
        if (menuItem.TargetType == null)
            return;

        Page displayPage;
        try
        {
            if (menuItem.TargetType == typeof(WebPage))
                displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(menuItem.TargetType, menuItem.TargetUri, menuItem.Title);
            else
                displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(menuItem.TargetType);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(displayPage, true);
        }
        finally
        {
            ListViewOptions.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your MainAppPage.xaml and its cs file, if it is MVVM, its view model also!

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I amended the post with xaml file & the code behind

Comment: In MasterPage.xaml, try icon=slideout.png property, you should have icon in drawable folder.. I am not sure this will work, I didn't check it